# how to get records from two different queries in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2.

When I find all the records from the table, this query runs fine:

```
    $users =  User::get(); // this query gives me all data from user table
```

But when I execute the query below, it's giving me an empty array. I don't know why?

```
    $users = new User();
    $users->get();// this query gives me empty result
```

Comment: $users = new User();
    $users->get();// this query gives me empty result 

what exactly you are trying to do here ? you create new user and you dont insert any data so its totally normal that you recieve empty result

Comment: try : before class add `use App\User;` and change here `$users = new User;` remove `()` Sign

Comment: @Niklesh stiil is empty array

Comment: share complete code how you print code also ?

Comment: $user= new User;
   $user->get();
   $user= json_decode(json_encode($user),true);
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($user); die;

Comment: I am getting result using  second method but you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't you get a User-Model object you can try this:

```
$users = User::query(); //not equal with $users = new User();
$result = $users->get();
dd($result);
```

Comment: still get an empty array :(

Comment: Remember that the `get()` call will return a value you have to save, updated my answer

Comment: it is not possible with $users variable again

Comment: what do you mean with again? Please post your full code

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = new User();
```

is used to initialize a new User Model and create a new user. So you can't use get() to retrieve the data.